# Ignore Error Code 2 PSFTP

Tags: file, psftp

We have an desktop application that dynamically generates a command file to pull specific files that have the current date in the name. So in the end we have a command file that looks like this:

```
lcd e:\localpath
mget Filename0111.dat
mget Filenametwo0111.dat
mget Filenamethree0111.dat
bye
```

Where 0111 is MMDD. The command file is created via a .bat file that the desktop app executes. The application then connects to the remote server via PSFTP.exe and runs that command file to pull files.
The problem we're running into is we updated the PSFTP.exe to a newer version due to a separate issue that occurred. Now if a file is not available on the remote server it returns an error code 2 which stops the rest of the files from being retrieved. So if the first file in the list doesn't exist then it fails and the rest of the files are not downloaded.

Is there a way to ignore the error code 2 so that the rest of the files get retrieved? I had thought at first to run PSFTP.exe and it's commands through a batch file but that didn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

PSFTP.exe has a command -be that will continue executing the batch if there is an issue.

> When running a batch file, this option causes PSFTP to continue processing even if a command fails to complete successfully.
>
> You might want this to happen if you wanted to delete a file and didn't care if it was already not present, for example.